# why are my express sub routes not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

why are these two endpoints not working with `routes.use`
`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/students`
`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/teachers`
while my `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api` and `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/api` are working just fine.
I am using express.js server and `router()` with typscript.

this my server.ts file

```
import express from 'express';
import routes from './routes/index'

// create an application object
const app = express();
// defint a port
const port = 3000;

//apply router middleware to application
app.use('/api', routes);


// define a route handler for hompage
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, world!\n welcome to the server.');
});


//start the express server
app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log(`server started at localhost:${port}`)
});
```

this my index.ts inside ./src/routes directory

```
import express from 'express';
import students from './api/students';
import teachers from './api/teachers';

const routes = express.Router();

// define a route handler for hompage
routes.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('connected to the server. main api route');
});
// define routes fro other paths
// routes.get('/api', (req, res) => {
//     res.send('connected to the server. secondary api route');
// });
routes.use('/api', routes);
routes.use('/students', students);
routes.use('/teachers', teachers);

export default routes;
```

and this students.ts in ./src/routes/api

```
import express from 'express';
const students = express.Router();


// define a route handler for api/students
students.get('/students', (req, res) => {
    res.send('connected to the server. students route');
});

export default students;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the actual endpoint for the API for the students.ts is: **/api/students/students** because in the student.js file the path starts from the /students so the final URL will be 
 **http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/students/students**

Moreover, if the endpoint in the students.ts file is changed from **/students** to **/** then it will work with the **http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/students** URL